# Framework7 click button from a popup to open another popup not working

Tags: jquery, button, html-framework-7

I have  a popup and inside the popup there is a button. I am using `Framework7` for my page. My code as follows:

```
<div class="loginform">
                  <span id="pswd_success_span" style="color :#7cbe55;font-weight:700;"></span>
                  <p><a href="#" data-popup=".popup-login" class="button first_page">Go to Login</a></p>
                </div>
```

I am trying to open another popup in clik function of the **Go to Login** button as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/Redirect popup to login popup
    var myApp = new Framework7();
    var $$ = Dom7;

    $$('.first_page').on('click', function(){
                alert("test");
                myApp.popup('.popup-login');
         });
});
```

Where popup login is another popup div just like above div

```
<div class="loginform">
    <--login popup-->               
</div>
```

When I click button I am getting the alert test but not opening the login div. Checked console there are no errors. please help me.

Comment: could you just try and change the class name of div from loginform to something else and specify new class name in 
myApp.popup('.newClass')

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure with Framework7. But in jQuery the dot is a selector for Classes. You just have a data-property with the name ".popup-login".

Watch this example.
https://framework7.io/docs/popup.html

As you can see in the example under "Using JavaScript" the div has the classname witch is called from Javascript later.

HTML:

```
 <div class="popup popup-about"> --- Popup --- </div>
```

Javascript:

```
myApp.popup('.popup-about');
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. But the issue seems to be different I solved it using closeModal.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it using the following and now it works fine,

```
$$('.first_page').on('click', function(){
        myApp.closeModal('.popup-forgot');
});
```